# How to save username and password for a WiFi network that doesn't require password but requires authentication via web page

Tags: macos, mac, wifi, password, keychain

I'm having difficulties figuring out a way to save my username and password (in Network Preference and Keychain Access) for a WiFi network that doesn't require password but every time I connect to it, it opens a web page for me to enter my username and password. The page might be accessed through a browser, but usually upon connecting to the wifi it automatically shows up in a system window (titled: Join "Network Name").

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sometimes, the Form auto-fill button will remember things like this, even if Keychain never offers. I obviously can't test that for your instance.

Comment: Is there any option to store/load a password from Keychain when you right click on the username or password field?